# Pro*c exec command not working

Tags: oracle, proc

> Error at line 16, column 1 in file glssim.pc
>   EXEC SQL
>   1
>   PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "exec sql begin" when expecting one of      the following:
>
> Syntax error at line 0, column 0, file glssim.pc:
>   Error at line 0, column 0 in file glssim.pc
>   PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "eof" when expecting one of the following:
>
> an identifier, end-exec, random_terminal
>
> Error at line 0, column 0 in file glssim.pc
>   PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing

I think the problem is related to exec library but I need to know where's it and where to add it.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your Pro\*C code is doing? Edit your question to include the properly-formatted code, and maybe the `proc` command you're using.

Comment: thank you for your reply I am using proc command, I solved this issue,
by changing the order of the sys_include librairies in configuration file.
Now I have an other issue : the compiler is not recognizing functions
e.g : int function (void);
       int function(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to function prototypes defined, in a header file, for wich the body was not defined.
Then the precompiler is waiting for their definitions, when it faces new functions it complains.
I just deleted the useless function prototypes. and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply I am using proc command, I solved this issue,
by changing the order of the sys_include librairies in configuration file.
Now I have an other issue : the compiler is not recognizing functions

e.g : int function (void);
       int function(){
        some code
        }

the compiler is saying Encountered the symbol {
when expecting one of the following ;= ([